Replacement for Team Viewer
I have been using Team Viewer for some time, for personal use.  Its is hardly more than 10 or 20 hours a year.  Yet, increasingly their AI! keeps telling me its commercial use.  I created a new account and it worked for a while.  Now, if the connection fails, then it won't let me connect for another day.
So, I have decided to give up on it.  I am looking for basic remote control of my pc from my laptop, when I am travelling.

Nothing fancy
Multiple screens are not required.
Even speed is not much of an issue.
Cost is, as I am not making money from it, so free or a one time license is fine.
The two uses of it are

Looking at the local devices on the network in a local browser
Looking at stored documents



All machines are windows 10.  I may update the laptop to Windows 11, but not my main PC.
There are a few more questions that are similar, but they aren't the same.  My use is different and the other questions have not provided me with an answer.

Do the remote PCs have a public IP thus can you directly connect to them or is a connection redirector as TeamViewer uses it required?

My home desktop has fixed ip, and my normal use is to remote into my desktop.

I ended up using AnyDesk.  It was really easy to get it started.  I was not sure if I needed to open ports, but I did anyway.  I am using the free version and have no need to upgrade.
I found it surprisingly fast and required no setup on the client.  It is a little tricky to name the connections.  The only way to do this to add them to the address book, where you can give them names.

Rust Desk is an open source alternative to Team Viewer and supports basically the same use cases and roughly the same features as team viewer.
It doesn't require creating an account or signing up, although you can for additional benefits.
It supports remote desktop sessions and has an Android mobile app. You can write your own relay server if you like to for complete independence.

If I understand it correctly you need to pay monthly or you have to set-up an own server that manages the connections between remote controlled devices and remote controllers.

Not really sure what the payed version gives you access to, but there is a free community version of the server without subscription you can download. Non self hosted server is also free
